# Converting State object array into <li> ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to the ReactJS and I'm making simple To-Do app,I already implemented Add,Delete,Edit functionalities.Now I'm messing around with Pagination.
I'm stuck on Display part.

```
state = {
        inputValue: '',
        todos: [],
        currentPage:1,
        pageCount:1,
    };

    inpRef = createRef();

    setPageCount = () => {
            let {todos} = this.state
          this.setState({pageCount: Math.ceil(todos.length / 5)})
            console.log('--------this.state.pageCount', this.state.pageCount );
    }

paginationDisplay = () => {
    let {todos,currentPage} = this.state
    const start = this.setState({currentPage:(currentPage - 1)*5 })
    const end = start+5
    todos.forEach((item,index) => {
        if(index >= start && index < end) {
            item.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            item.style.display = "none";
        }
    })
}

        renderPagination = () => {
    let {pageCount,currentPage} = this.state

    const paging = []

    for (let i=1;i<pageCount; i++){
        paging.push(
            <button key={uuidv4()}
                className={'btn btn-info'}
                onClick={() => {
                    this.paginationDisplay()
                    currentPage = i}}>
                {i}
            </button>
        )
    }
    return paging
}



        }
addItem = () => {
        let {inputValue, todos} = this.state
        if (this.inpRef.current.value === '') {
            return alert('We dont do that here....')
        } else {
            this.setState({todos: [...todos, {inputValue, id: uuidv4()}]})
            this.inpRef.current.value = ''
        }
        this.setPageCount()
        this.paginationDisplay()
    }

            render() {
            const { todos } = this.state;

            return <div className={"App"}>
                <div className="App-header">
                    <h2>Welcome to To-Do List App</h2>
                </div>
                <input ref={this.inpRef} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.handleInputValue} name={''} type='text'/>
                <button onClick={() => this.addItem()} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Add</button>
                <ul>
                    {
                        todos.map(todoItem => <ListItem
                            key={todoItem.id}
                            todoItem={todoItem}
                            deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
                            editItem={this.editItem}
                            submitEdit={this.submitEdit}
                        />)
                    }
                    {this.renderPagination()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        };
    }
```

I want this function to get all Elements from `<ul>` and Change it's style display,As I get I'm trying to mutate style of state Elements in Array.But  I don't know how to get all `<li>` from `<ul>`.Please Help

```
paginationDisplay = () => {
        let {todos,currentPage} = this.state
        const start = this.setState({currentPage:(currentPage - 1)*5 })
        const end = start+5
        todos.forEach((item,index) => {
            if(index >= start && index < end) {
                item.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                item.style.display = "none";
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: can you make a sandbox for you code?

Comment: `const start = this.setState({currentPage:(currentPage - 1)*5 })` setState doesn't return anything

Comment: You are mutating state in paginationDisplay: `item.style.display = "block";`

Comment: I know,i Just dont know how to get <li> to change its style display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place Pagination as a separate component

**Example**

```js
const { Component, createRef, useState, useEffect } = React;

const uuidv4 = (() => {
  let id = 0;
  
  return () => id++;
})()

const Pagination = ({page, onPageSelected, pageCount}) => {

  if(pageCount <= 1) {
    return null;
  }

  const computeClass = (currentPage) => `${page === currentPage ? 'selected' : ''} btn btn-info`

  return <div>
    {[...Array(pageCount).keys()].map(pr => <button key={pr}
      className={computeClass()}
      disabled={page === pr}
      onClick={() => onPageSelected(pr)}>
      {pr + 1}
    </button>)}
  </div>
}
 
const ListItem = ({todoItem, editItem, submitEdit, deleteItem}) => {
  return <div>{todoItem.inputValue}</div>
}

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
      todos: [],
      pagedTodos: [],
      currentPage: 0,
      pageCount: 0,
      pageSize: 1
    };

    this.inpRef = createRef();
    this.handleInputValue = this.handleInputValue.bind(this);
    this.onPageSelected = this.onPageSelected.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputValue({target: {value: inputValue}}) {
    this.setState(state => ({...state, inputValue}))
  }

  addItem = () => {
        const { inputValue, pageSize } = this.state;
        
        if (this.inpRef.current.value === '') {
            return alert('We dont do that here....')
        } else {
            const todo = { inputValue, id: uuidv4() };

            this.setState(state => {
              const todos = [...state.todos, todo];
              const pageCount = Math.ceil(todos.length / pageSize);
              const currentPage = pageCount - 1; // set last page
              const from = currentPage * pageSize
              const to = from + pageSize;
              const pagedTodos = todos.slice(from, to);
            
              return {
                ...state,
                todos,
                currentPage,
                pagedTodos,
                pageCount
              }}
            )
            this.inpRef.current.value = ''
        }
    }
    
    onPageSelected(currentPage) {
      this.setState(state => {
        const { pageSize, todos } = state;
        const from = currentPage * pageSize
        const to = from + pageSize;
        const pagedTodos = todos.slice(from, to);
        
        return {
          ...state,
          currentPage,
          pagedTodos
        }
      })
    }

    render() {
            const { pagedTodos, currentPage, pageCount } = this.state;

            return <div className={"App"}>
                <div className="App-header">
                    <h2>Welcome to To-Do List App</h2>
                </div>
                <input ref={this.inpRef} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onChange={this.handleInputValue} name={''} type='text'/>
                <button onClick={this.addItem} className={'btn btn-primary'}>Add</button>
                <ul>
                    {
                        pagedTodos.map(todoItem => <ListItem
                            key={todoItem.id}
                            todoItem={todoItem}
                            deleteItem={this.deleteItem}
                            editItem={this.editItem}
                            submitEdit={this.submitEdit}
                        />)
                    }
                    <Pagination onPageSelected={this.onPageSelected} page={currentPage} pageCount={pageCount}/>
                </ul>
            </div>
        };
    }

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```